# Android httppost without result

Tags: android

I'm trying to post a string to a php script. This script gives back a string with values that a devided by semicolons (like "hello;world").

I implemented a test for this string so i can test it in my browser and it works. But my App does not get any results.

Here is my Code

```
public class GetInformationForBarcode extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Product> {

    public String url = "myexample.com" //yes, in my code it is a real url ;)

    private Product getInformationForBarcode(String barcode) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(this.url);

        try {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ean", barcode));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            if( response.getEntity().getContentLength() > 0){
                Product product = new Product();
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader =
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()), 65728);
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    String[] productData = sb.toString().split(";");

                    product.setName(productData[0]);
                    product.setProducer(productData[1]);
                }
                catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                Log.e("finalResult " , sb.toString());
                product.setBarcode(barcode);
                return product;
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Product doInBackground(String... param) {
        getInformationForBarcode(result);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this check

```
 if( response.getEntity().getContentLength() > 0)
```

is not correct. The http header  `ContentLength` could be set to 0. The rfc doesn't force to specify the correct size. You should check the response code of the the http's request instead. The check should be:

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
```

then try to read the content of the response. By rfc HTTP 200 is `request ok` and  `HTTP 204` is `Request ok No Content`

Comment: He does not do the if. The last line I can get is the execute. After that he breaks the try. 

09-28 10:53:51.824  16318-16601/? E/log_tag﹕ Error:  javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Thats what I get.